# Send array to mysql row and break it up into variables again

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for clients that stores some basic info but in one row it also stores an array that looks something like this i.e.
"1-1, 2-1, 3-1, 6-1, 7-1, 16-1, 17-1, 18-1"

the commas separate the "options", the number before the dash is the "option" ID, and the number after after the dash is the "option's" "quantity". each client might have different "options" with different "quantities"

I have this so far but I have no idea where to go from here.

```
<?php
        $out = "";
        $id_client ="";
        $id_client = $_SESSION['client_cod_card'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE client_cod_card='$id_client'";
  $result = mysql_query ($sql);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

      $in = $row['options'];
      $out = str_replace(',', '<br />', $in);

      echo $out;} ?>
```

and it gives me this

1-1
2-1
3-1
6-1
7-1
16-1
17-1
18-1

is there any way to echo that string into something like:

$option_id - $option_quantity 
$option_id - $option_quantity 
$option_id - $option_quantity 
$option_id - $option_quantity 
..

so I can use those numbers and get each option's info from another table and adjust the quantity.

I hope I managed to explain this somewhat understandable and I hope someone can give me a hand as this is the most frustrating thing I've gotten myself into. 
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: It's not a good idea to store comma-separated values in databases. It makes search and updating very difficult.

Comment: though I completely agree with Barmar (who couldn't?), this might help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: @Barmar your solution is perfect! I know I've bitten more than I can chew with this project but getting stuck is the only way to learn new things in this domain :)) Thank You!

Comment: @Jeff Serialize output can contain NULL bytes, notably when encoding private object properties, and MySQL does not play well with unescaped NULL bytes. I would suggest `json_encode()` instead, but once again storing serialized data like OP wants to is a super bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode()` to split up the value into its parts. First split the whole list on the commas, then split each option on the hyphens.

```
$option_array = explode(',', $row['options'];
foreach ($option_array as $opt) {
    list($option_id, $option_quantity) = explode('-', $opt);
    // Use $option_id and $option_quantity here
}
```